# how to extract array data only having multiple value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-5

i have this array data.

```
var arr = {key1:'progress',key2:'done',key3:['new','12'],key4:['checking','10']};
```

and i want extract array data,but it should only having multiple value data.
so i want to get result array like this.

```
var result = {['new','12'],['checking','10']};
```

or

```
var result = {key3:['new','12'],key4:['checking','10']};
```

i googled for solving this but i couldnt get answer.
is there way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `filter` the `Object.values` array based on whether a value is an array (using [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)) and checking its `length`:

```js
var arr = {
  key1: 'progress',
  key2: 'done',
  key3: ['new', '12'],
  key4: ['checking', '10']
};

var result = Object.values(arr).filter(v => Array.isArray(v) && v.length > 1);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the previous answer, if you want to exactly get `{key3:['new','12'],key4:['checking','10']}` as result value, you need to then use the array values you found to build a new object.

It can be done like this, by looping on the `keys` of the original `arr`, checking each value against the `arrayValues` you found, and creating a new key-value pair in the `result` object when a match is found

```js
var arr = {
  key1: 'progress',
  key2: 'done',
  key3: ['new', '12'],
  key4: ['checking', '10']
};

var arrayValues = Object.values(arr).filter(v => Array.isArray(v) && v.length > 1);

let result = {}
Object.keys(arr).forEach(key => arrayValues.includes(arr[key]) ? result[key] = arr[key] : null)

console.log(result);
```

There are many more elegant ways of doing this, though.

Answer (score 0):

after I got nice answer,I made GoogleAppsScript ver for this.
sometime i use GAS, but GAS can't use some method like "Object.values".
(but it can be use in GAS HTML)
hope it helps for someone.

```
        var arr = {
      key1: 'progress',
      key2: 'done',
      key3: ['new', '12'],
      key4: ['checking', '10']
    };

      var keys = Object.keys(arr)
      var values = keys.map(function(x) {
        return arr[x];
      });


    var result = values.filter(function (v) {
      return Array.isArray(v) && v.length > 1;
    });
    Logger.log(result);
//[[new, 12], [checking, 10]]
```